# How to gradually blend two materials together?

Tags: materials

I have a simple stick whose one end has material A and the other one has material B assigned to its faces. How do I blend these materials gradually, instead of a hard line, so that I can control the location and smoothness of the blend?

I have found many solutions for older Blender versions but not for 2.8 and Eevee.

Comment: you can use a Mix Shader to mix 2 chains of nodes, and use a gradient as factor, but if you give more details on how your material looks like it would help

Comment: I would like to use two different, already defined materials that are already being used elsewhere in the project. I don't know how it would be possible to combine two materials into the Mix Shader.

Comment: If you want to use already made materials, you can group the nodes of these materials, create a third material, add the 2 groups, and mix them in a Mix Shader with a gradient plugged into the factor of a Mix Shader, but maybe share your file so that I can show you? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There may be another way but here is one. Let say you have 2 materials that you want to keep separate. If you want to mix them, you need to create a third material. To keep your 2 materials somehow linked to the third, here is what you could do:

Here is your material 1:

[image]

Select the chain of nodes before *Material Output* and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to group them. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to exit the group (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> if you ever want to ungroup). Do the same thing for the second material.

[image]

Now create your third material, press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Group* and load the 2 groups you've created. Plug them into a *Mix Shader*:

[image]

To create a transition between group 1 and 2, plug this node chain into the *factor* of the *Mix Shader*: *(Input) Texture Coordinate > (Vector) Mapping > (Converter) Separate XYZ > (Texture) Gradient > (Converter) ColorRamp*. You can control the transition with the needles of the *ColorRamp*.

[image]

Of course you could create the transition with an *Image Texture* instead of this node chain.

Now if you ever need to change material 1 or material 2 you can open the group in material 1 or material 2 or material 3 and the change will be taken into account into the other materials that have the same group.

Comment: Super brilliant! Thank you very much for making a simple to understand instructions! You made my day :)

Comment: If you don't understand something, don't hesitate to ask, depending on your object orientation you may need to choose the X, Y or Z  output socket in the Separate XYZ