# Mixing Materials in Blender efficiently

Tags: materials, shader-nodes

Oftentimes you’ll want to mix materials with a mask. Blender makes it super easy to mix *shaders*, but *materials* seem to be a different story. The closest thing I can think of is copying the material’s nodes into a new material and mixing the shaders like that. The fastest way I can think of doing that is

- Appending a material
- Opening the material in the shader editor
- Selecting all nodes except for the Material Output
- Copying
- Pasting in a new material
- Making sure all of the outputs that used to go into the Material Output get mixed appropriately
- Repeat for every material
- (If more than 2 materials, make sure every individual “mix” shader aligns to the proper channel of your mask)

Is there a more efficient way of doing this that I just don’t know about?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190858/how-to-gradually-blend-two-materials-together https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh/748#748

Comment: This is the same as the inefficient solution I was trying to avoid.